# Launching C# .Net application from browser. Possible?

Tags: c#, .net, browser

The greatest example I can think of is the Google Chrome installation.

I remember one other application launching that same way. Can't remember what it was.
I'm not implying that it was built in C# or even .Net.

It is possible somehow. It's been done. Just wondering how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx) deployment.

> ClickOnce deployment allows you to publish Windows-based applications to a Web server or network file share for simplified installation

Comment: +1 for correct.  ClickOnce deployment can be a real treat for a user experience.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Someone else has already pointed out ClickOnce, and this is probably want you want. Another alternative is Silverlight, where the application runs inside the browser window.

Comment: Silverlight is indeed something I may try out later on. For this project, I'll stick with clickOnce. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about launching an application or installing it? You can launch an application by registering your application has a protocol handler (such as http://) within Windows...different browsers will have different behaviors, but it's possible that way. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx) link for information.

Comment: Wow! Indeed... I've tried (briefly) working with protocol handlers in the past and I just have bad memories. That's why I didn't even remember it for this project. But indeed... It would work as well.

Comment: This approach works well for internal applications where desktop builds and browsers are standardized.